# wall posts and fb:multi-friend-selector

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-c#-sdk

Firstly i know that the documentation provided by Facebook says that fb:multi-friend-selector can be used in pair with fb:request-form and that it could only sends inviations or requests.

I have more specific need and that is not only to make invitations/requests but also along with the previous to post something on selected friends walls.
I've tried everything but i cant take the id's selected from the fb:multi-friend-selector, so i'm unable to make this posts.

The doucmentation for fb:multi-friend-selector says: **This interface includes a series of  which are included for selected users in the form that gets submitted to your action URL.**

Is it somehow possible to catch this id's?
I'm working on my app in C# .net.

I read in some of the previous posts that is treating problematics similar to mine that is impossible to do this, but i found application that works perfectly in way that i want to make my application.

Thanks in advance,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You can access the selected friend's id in the page that you are providing in "action" of fb:request-form.I am working with PHP so i am able to get those selected friend's id as $_REQUEST['ids'].So try some equivalent methods in c# for this.And if you get the friend's id you can publish to their wall.

Comment: Thanks Damodaran it finally works, i'm using Request.QueryString.GetValues to take the values, but it is only possible if the method is GET, and i think that doesn't make any difference.